# Compare two tables and return only rows that have a distinct value - EDITED per suggestions thank you

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code and I want to show only the rows in the first table where the `IVRCPT.RECEIVER_NO` is not the same as the `PDINVRCPT.RCVR_NO` in the second table. But it still shows rows in `IVRCPT` that are also in `PDINVRCPT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT     FORMAT(IHRCPT.RECEIVE_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "Date Received",
                    IHRCPT.PO_NO AS "PO",
                    IHRCPT.RECEIVER_NO AS "Receiver",
                    PMVEND.VENDOR_NAME AS "Vendor"              
FROM                IHRCPT (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN          PMVEND (NOLOCK) ON PMVEND.VENDOR_CODE = IHRCPT.VENDOR_CODE
ORDER BY            IHRCPT.RECEIVER_NO

SELECT              *
FROM                PDINVRCPT
ORDER BY            PDINVRCPT.RCVR_NO
```

Here is a sample of the output:

```
Date Received    PO       Receiver  Vendor
-----------------------------------------------------------
12/16/2019       124         123    DICARLO SEAFOOD COMPANY       
12/16/2019       122         124    UNIFIED SEAFOOD               
12/16/2019       123         125    MAGURO INTERNATIONAL          
12/16/2019       125         126    LOAD                          
12/16/2019       126         127    LOAD                          
12/16/2019       127         128    OCEAN CRYSTAL SEAFOOD 


VENDOR_CODE INVOICE_NO  LINE_NO PO_NO   RCVR_NO
------------------------------------------------
      4944      233331  001      123         125
      1220      499476  001      134         135
       970  0854392-IN  001      137         138
      1250      192251  001      141         142
      4624      199188  001      142         143
```

As you can see the Receiver number 125 is in the first table and RCVR number 125 is also in the second table. I do not want to show the row containing Receiver Number 125 in the first table.

Comment: FYI: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: You should be testing for one of the two columns being NULL, which would mean there was no matching value. The NULL columns will be returned because of your `OUTER JOIN`.For future reference, a [mcve] for SQL includes sample data and the output you're wanting to obtain from that data, as well as the least amount of code requierd to produce the problem. You've got a third table and many additional conditions that aren't relevant to the question asked in your SQL.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with your expected output from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE conditions as below and please post your observations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     FORMAT(IVRCPT.RECEIVE_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "Date Received",
                    IVRCPT.PO_NO AS "PO",
                    IVRCPT.RECEIVER_NO AS "Receiver",
                    PMVEND.VENDOR_NAME AS "Vendor"      
FROM                IVRCPT (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN          PMVEND (NOLOCK) ON PMVEND.VENDOR_CODE = IVRCPT.VENDOR_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN     PDINVRCPT (NOLOCK) ON   IVRCPT.RECEIVER_NO = PDINVRCPT.RCVR_NO   --  PDINVRCPT.VENDOR_CODE = IVRCPT.VENDOR_CODE
WHERE               PDINVRCPT.RCVR_NO IS NULL
ORDER BY            Receiver
```

If you could provide us sample & expected data then we could help further.

UPDATE: Per sample data, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccdeea27724ab6ef37db74181045b5c8) is dbfiddle

Comment: Sorry, I just read this answer, that seemed to work thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT     FORMAT(IVRCPT.RECEIVE_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS "Date Received",
                        IVRCPT.PO_NO AS "PO",
                        IVRCPT.RECEIVER_NO AS "Receiver",
                        PMVEND.VENDOR_NAME AS "Vendor"      
    FROM                IVRCPT (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN          PMVEND (NOLOCK) ON PMVEND.VENDOR_CODE = IVRCPT.VENDOR_CODE
    INNER JOIN          PDINVRCPT (NOLOCK) ON IVRCPT.RECEIVER_NO != PDINVRCPT.RCVR_NO
    ORDER BY            Receiver

    SELECT              *
    FROM                PDINVRCPT
    ORDER BY            PDINVRCPT.RCVR_NO
```